# Selenium select does not find option by index in PhantomJS

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, phantomjs, html-select

When I use Selector `obj.selectByIndex(randomIndex)` in chrome and firefox selector object finds the option at index `randomIndex` just fine, but in PhantomJS I get the exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with index: randomIndex.

This is the code:

```
Select selector = new Select(driver.findElement(positionDropDownList));
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1000,800));

selector.selectByIndex(positionIndex);
driver.findElement(hireDate).sendKeys(date);
driver.findElement(finish).click();
```

and this is the html code:

```
<select class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" name="q_1">
    <option class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" value="1">Sales Associate</option>
    <option class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" value="2">Retail Store Manager</option>
    <option class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" value="3">District Manager</option>
    <option class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" value="4">Regional Manager</option>
    <option class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" value="5">Owner</option>
    <option class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" value="6">Customer Service</option>
    <option class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" value="7">Training Manager</option>
    <option class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" value="8">Buyer</option>
    <option class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" value="9">General Manager</option>
    <option class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" value="10">Manufacturer Rep</option>
    <template class="style-scope exp-affiliation-application-form" as="answer" is="dom-repeat"/>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you sure the complete element is loaded? Have you printed the page source to see if it is full? Maybe you need to wait a little. How big is `randomIndex` usually?

Comment: random is 0-9, the total option values are 10. I used a precondition wait first of 30 seconds, and then an explicit sleep of 10 seconds, to wait for all elements to load. I even printed the attribute value to see if it was visible. But it seems like Select has issues in phantomjs.